# how to write Or condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

is it correct?-

```
if (expiryMonth == "MM" || expiryMonth == "mm") {
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's correct. MDC (Mozilla Developer Center) has [plenty of information about logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's correct.  You may be able to avoid the use of `||` in this situation by using the *toLowerCase()* or *toUpperCase()* method on strings:

```
if (expiryMonth.toLowerCase() == "mm") {
```

or

```
if (expiryMonth.toUpperCase() == "MM") {
```

Of course, this would also match `Mm` and `mM`, as Tim points out in the comments.

- [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)
- [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: That's not equivalent: "Mm" and "mM" will satisfy the new condition but not the original.

Comment: @Tim: in which case, it might be better for him.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the need for the or statement and just set expiryMonth to lowercase.

**expiryMonth=expiryMonth.toLowerCase();**  // You can also use toUpperCase();

Then run your if statement.

Comment: That's not equivalent: "Mm" and "mM" will then satisfy the new condition but not the original.