# Google Spreadsheet link with Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a way of Google Spreadsheets recognising the existence of a certain file name and/or type from the Google Drive itself.

If the file exists, I'd like an "X" to be displayed in a box within the spreadsheet.

I am fairly new to gscript/javascript and I've had a play around but to no avail

I currently have this, however I am unsure how to piece code together properly:

```
function CheckIfFileExists(name, mimeType){
  var flag = false;
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(mimeType);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
     if(file.getName() == name) {
       flag = true;
         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue('Hello');
       break;
     }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

I'd appreciate a point in the right direction if you could.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use triple equal signs for comparison:

```
if(file.getName() === name) {
```

You need to add an "OR" condition check, which in JavaScript is accomplished with double pipes.

[StackOverflow - Or Condition in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718128/how-to-write-or-condition-in-javascript)

```
function CheckIfFileExists(name, mimeType){

  Logger.log('Value of name is: ' + name);

  var flag = false;
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(mimeType);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
     if(file.getName() === name || file.getMimeType() === mimeType) {
       flag = true;
         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue('X');
       break;
     }
  }

  return flag;
}
```

If your file name is the same all the time, then you don't need to pass a value, just hard code a value:

```
if(file.getName() === "A1" || file.getMimeType() === mimeType) {
```

Note the "hardcoded" file name "A1".  And it is in double quotes, making it a "string". (Text value)

If you want to pass a different file name to the function every time, then the function call must include the values to pass:

Function call:

```
//This causes the function to run, and passes two values to 
//the arguments specified in the arguments parameter.
CheckIfFileExists("A1", "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
```

If you pass values to the function, don't hard code the value to check in the `If` statement.  Leave the `name` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however it still will not show up in Google Sheets and I don't know why. I have a file named "A1" in my drive, renamed "name" on both parts of code to "A1" (without quote marks) and that file won't be crossed off in a cell.

Comment: You need to debug your code.  Use `Logger.log('value of name is: ' + name);` in your code, then VIEW the LOGS from the menu.  (See update in my answer) Or set a break point, and use the debugger, and step through each line of code.  "name" is a variable.  If no value is passed to the "name" argument in the `CheckIfFileExists(name, mimeType)` function, then the value of `name` is undefined.  Renaming your file to "name" won't make a match.  "name" does not equal `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now have the log and it is saying the value of "name" is undefined. How do I go about defining the value? Sorry, I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I added some info at the end of my answer.